# ASP.NET Membership user login error cookie problems

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, asp.net-membership

We recently updated a site from Classic ASP to ASP.Net 3.5.

The old site used a login system based on cookies. 
It would remember the users login information if a checkbox was selected when they first logged in. This would of course be done in a cookie.

We then upgraded the site Using ASP.net. 
We transferred the old users to the built in ASP.net Membership Authentication.

It works great except for a really strange occurrence. 
When a user logs in to the site, but had the old cookie for the site which stored the login information, the ASP.net Authentication seems to crash.

There is no error message, no information of any kind.

The user tries to login, gets no error message, just gets transfered back to the login page.

It seems to be looking at the old cookie and just doesn't know what to do.

The domain names of the old site and the new site are the same.

This does not occur for new users who have never been to the old site.

If an old site user clears out his cookies in his browser he can log in fine and the error never happens again.

But we have 5000 users, we can't tell all of them to clear out their cookies.

I tried changing the setting in the following line of code in my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~\User\Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~\Default.aspx" timeout="26280000"  />
</authentication>
```

But I'm not sure if it helped or not.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With forms authentication, your login is controlled by forms authentication cookie. So I don't understand how is your old cookie interfering with FAC?

In case you are storing some value in your custom cookie, one way would be change the name of the cookie in your new code. i.e. if the code is creating "CookieA", the same name as old application, change it to "CookieB" and same while reading.

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. It just doesn't make sense, I know the old cookie shouldn't be interfering with the new one, but the only way to get old users to login is to clear their cookies first. Could there be something else going on?

Comment: Do you have any machine where you can replicate this? If so you can use firebug or other tools to inspect the cookies. Also make sure to remove any reference to old cookie in your code.

Comment: I finally got it. The cookies were using the same name. The old site used the same name but in all lower case while the new site using uppercase letter I assumed that was okay, it considered them the same cookie.

Comment: @matwonk - Changing the name of the cookie as this answer suggested solved your problem.  Please upvote this answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Specify cookies token name:

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" ... />
```